# Visual Studio C# web form checkbox CheckedChanged method error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, checkbox, webforms

this is my fist question, I have been searching about how to use checkbox in a c# web form, and I found some codes that almost is what I need, but I keep getting an error because all those codes does not apply for C# web forms specifically.

File.aspx has this code:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbxScheduleDate" runat="server" Text="Schedule for today" AutoPostBack="true"; OnCheckedChanged="cbxScheduleDate_CheckedChanged"/>
```

File.aspx.cs has this code:

```
protected void cbxScheduleDate_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbxScheduleDate.Checked)
            txtScheduleDate.Visible = false;
        else
            txtScheduleDate.Visible = true;

    }
```

So, what I need is when the checkbox is checked I make the txtScheduleDate textbox not visible.

Right now with that code, Visual Studio has the error:

> The name 'cbxScheduleDate' does not exist in the current context

Does anyone now how to solve this Visual Studio error, or another way to make this work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your asp tag is not well formed. There is a semi-colon in there after

```
autopostback="true"
```

which is not required.

Comment: OMG! Shame on me... Yes, you are absolutely right. I just removed that and it is working now. Maybe dealing with the same issue for too long make your brain not see things. Thank you!!!